# How to reset dropdown values when an option is selected from another dropdown in React.js

Tags: reactjs

If the user select the number `3` from the `numbers` drop down, this will make the `names` drop down to be disabled.
I want to reset the names dropdown to "select name" when option 3 is selected.

```js
const DropDown = ({ selectedValue, disabled, options, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <select onChange={onChange} disabled={disabled}>
      {
        options.map(o => <option value={o} selected={o == selectedValue}>{o}</option>)
      }
    </select>
  );
}


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // 3 should disable the second dropdown and reset
      names: ['john', 'jane', 'eric'],
      selectedNumber: '',
      selectedName: ''
    }

    this.onNumbersChange = this.onNumbersChange.bind(this);
    this.onNamesChange = this.onNamesChange.bind(this);
  }

  onNumbersChange(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedNumber: e.target.value });
  }

  onNamesChange(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedName: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const { numbers, names, selectedNumber, selectedName } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <DropDown
          options={numbers}
          selectedValue={selectedNumber}
          onChange={this.onNumbersChange}

        />
        <DropDown
          options={names}
          selectedValue={selectedName}
          onChange={this.onNamesChange}
          disabled={selectedNumber == 3} // this will be disabled if selected value of the first dropdown is 3
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

my dropdown is using redux form, field.

```
<Field name="Name" 
 component={renderSelect} 
 label="" 
 disabled options={options} 
 returnValue={"id"} 
 displayText={"name"} 
/>
```

so this is my dropdown.. I am not able to reset its value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make 2 changes

1. in `onNumbersChange` function, check if `e.target.value` is equal to 3. if it is, updated `selectedValue` in the state to be `'select name'`
2. in `DropDown` component, if `selectedValue` prop is equal to `'select name'`, add an extra option with the value of `'select name'` and add `selected` attribute on it.

```js
const DropDown = ({ selectedValue, disabled, options, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <select onChange={onChange} disabled={disabled}>
      { 
         selectedValue === 'select name'
           ? <option value={selectedValue} selected>{ selectedValue }</option>
           : null
      }
      {
        options.map(o => <option value={o} selected={o == selectedValue}>{o}</option>)
      }
    </select>
  );
}


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // 3 should disable the second dropdown and reset
      names: ['john', 'jane', 'eric'],
      selectedNumber: '',
      selectedName: ''
    }

    this.onNumbersChange = this.onNumbersChange.bind(this);
    this.onNamesChange = this.onNamesChange.bind(this);
  }

  onNumbersChange(e) {
    if (e.target.value == 3) {
       this.setState({ selectedName: 'select name' });
    }
    this.setState({ selectedNumber: e.target.value });
  }

  onNamesChange(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedName: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const { numbers, names, selectedNumber, selectedName } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <DropDown
          options={numbers}
          selectedValue={selectedNumber}
          onChange={this.onNumbersChange}

        />
        <DropDown
          options={names}
          selectedValue={selectedName}
          onChange={this.onNamesChange}
          disabled={selectedNumber == 3} // this will be disabled if selected value of the first dropdown is 3
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

A better approach would be to add `'select name'` in the names array in your state because after adding `'select name'` in your state, you will only need to make some changes in the `App` component to get the required functionality.

```js
const DropDown = ({ selectedValue, disabled, options, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <select onChange={onChange} disabled={disabled}>
      {
        options.map(o => <option value={o} selected={o == selectedValue}>{o}</option>)
      }
    </select>
  );
}


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // 3 should disable the second dropdown and reset
      names: ['select name', 'john', 'jane', 'eric'],
      selectedNumber: '',
      selectedName: ''
    }

    this.onNumbersChange = this.onNumbersChange.bind(this);
    this.onNamesChange = this.onNamesChange.bind(this);
  }

  onNumbersChange(e) {
    if (e.target.value == 3) {
       this.setState({ selectedName: this.state.names[0] });
    }
    this.setState({ selectedNumber: e.target.value });
  }

  onNamesChange(e) {
    this.setState({ selectedName: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const { numbers, names, selectedNumber, selectedName } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <DropDown
          options={numbers}
          selectedValue={selectedNumber}
          onChange={this.onNumbersChange}

        />
        <DropDown
          options={names}
          selectedValue={selectedName}
          onChange={this.onNamesChange}
          disabled={selectedNumber == 3} // this will be disabled if selected value of the first dropdown is 3
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Here numbers is coming from state..so in theonNumbersChange function, it is written this.state.names[0], how do i write it of numbers was coming from render funtion.. In a diff code my numbers option value is coming from an api, and I have defined it first in render...so how to make write that

Comment: when you get the numbers from the api, save them in the state. No need to define them in render function

Comment: my dropdown is using redux form, field.     <Field
                        name="Name"
                        component={renderSelect}
                        label=""
                        disabled
                        options={options}
                        returnValue={"id"}
                        displayText={"name"}
                      /> so this is my dropdown.. I am not able to reset its value

Comment: i have edited it in the question...I dont know why i am not able to reset for this method